why is my java fetch redis programe so slow
    for(String record:records){
        JSONObject json= JSONUtil.parseObj(record);
        OpintionObject opintionObject = JSONUtil.toBean(json, OpintionObject.class);
        
        String resourceKey=RedisConstant.VISIT_RESOURCE_KEY+opintionObject.getId();
        
        List<String> resourceTiming= redisTemplate.opsForList().range(resourceKey + RedisConstant.RESOURCE_TIMING, 0, -1);//about 100 size
        List<String> navigationTiming = redisTemplate.opsForList().range(resourceKey + RedisConstant.NAVIGATION_TIMING, 0, -1);
        
        deleteKeys.add(resourceKey+RedisConstant.RESOURCE_TIMING);
        deleteKeys.add(resourceKey+RedisConstant.NAVIGATION_TIMING);
        
        List<PerformanceNavigationTiming>performanceNavigationTimingsTmp=navigationTiming.stream().map(e-> JSONUtil.toBean(JSONUtil.parseObj(e), PerformanceNavigationTiming.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        List<PerformanceResourceTiming>performanceResourceTimingsTmp=resourceTiming.stream().map(e-> JSONUtil.toBean(JSONUtil.parseObj(e), PerformanceResourceTiming.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        performanceResourceTimings.addAll(performanceResourceTimingsTmp);
        performanceNavigationTimings.addAll(performanceNavigationTimingsTmp);
    }

records is a 10000 size List, each data like below:

This program cost about 6-8min to finish, I want to know why it is so slow

Don't post images of JSON. Having said that, have you tried profiling your code?
